# How to connect Pentaho to Ms Access

Tags: ms-access, jdbc, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I want to connect Pentaho to Ms Access, but the following notification appears.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have also made the following settings

[image]

Does anyone know how to set the driver and where can I download it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this topic have some ways about resolve problems with this connection

https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/214984-MS-Access-Driver/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).